Using created variable to calculate new variable in SQL
I was wondering if there is a way to refer to a created alias to in turn create a new alias via a calculation in SQL under the SELECT fuction.
Here is the snippet:
select 
  d.forename,
  d.surname,
  sum(positionorder=1) as race_wins,
  count(*) as race_starts,
  CONCAT(CAST((sum(positionorder=1)/count(*)*100) AS DECIMAL(10,1)),"%") as win_percent,
from results r

I'd like to create the "win_percent" alias simply by "race_wins/race_starts", but this gives me an 'Unknown column' error.
I've looked into the DECLARE function as well, but all examples seem to be ones where you set the alias to a single value, not one that is calculated from the dataset itself.

FYI they're called aliases, not variables.
